# \React\Promise\all($promises) doesn't work as expected in ReactPHP

Tags: php, promise, reactphp

Please note that I've also created an [issue](https://github.com/reactphp/promise/issues/129) on the related repo.

In the [documentation](https://reactphp.org/promise/#all), it says that this function will return a promise which will resolved after all the promises in the array have resolved.

Here is my implementation;

```
private function downloadListingImages($contents)
{
    $response = [];
    $name = 1;
    foreach ($contents['images'] as $image) {
        $response[] = $this->downloadImage($image, $name);
        $name++;
    }
    return $response;
}

private function downloadImage($link, $name)
{
    $guzzle = new Client([
        'handler' => HandlerStack::create(new HttpClientAdapter($this->loop)),
    ]);

    $promise = $guzzle->getAsync($link, [
        'save_to' => 'assets/' . $name . '.jpg',
    ]);

    return $promise;
}

$promises = $this->downloadListingImages($contents);
```

Now, everything is fine till this point. But want I want to do is get `$contents` from a request to my server. So I have a server implementation;

```
$server = new React\Http\Server(function (Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request) use ($promises) {

    \React\Promise\all($promises)->always(function($val) {
        file_put_contents('meh.txt', "meh");
    });

    return new React\Http\Response(
        200,
        array('Content-Type' => 'text/plain'),
        "Hello World!\n"
    );

});
```

What I expect here that `$server` returns an immediate response (which it does) and after a while see the `meh.txt` in my repo. However, it never falls to `always` callback. And even when I don't chain any function on `all` method, it just resolves itself. Shouldn't it wait until `then` or something similar to be called to be resolved? How can run my guzzle promises async and get informed when the work is finished?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the objects that passed to \React\Promise\all implement the method then, it works very well. E.g. \React\Promise\all works very fine with with \React\Promise\Promise() and also with \GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise.

So far I'm not able to reproduce this issue.

As you can see in the documentation the always-method doesn't accept any parameter. Consider to use then instead of always if you in need of a parameter.
Also consider that file_put_contents MAY blocking the event-loop.

I hope this helps.